# IOException : The network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database from my Java application. I am using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, Version : 0/1 to connect to the database. But DriverManager.getConnection() is giving me the "The network adapter could not establish the connection". This is not happening evertime. Its happening sometimes only, may be once in 8-10 times. The stack trace am getting is :

```
Driver Class : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, version 0/1
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:334)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.handleIOException(TTC7Protocol.java:3678)
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:352)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:365)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:547)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:347)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:316)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:297)
```

Since I am not getting this everytime, I am not able to guess that there is any connectivity issue. I can see lots of developers have the same problem, but for them it happens everytime. Please help me, since i am literally stuck in solving this problem.

Comment: it seems your network is keep dropping connection.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am encountering the same thing with Cisco UCCX. It started randomly one day, no changes had been made to the app.

Comment: @AsherMaximum, I didnt get this solved. I was getting this error once in a while, hence I did multiple connection attempts, and so far it had workd without issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a network issue:

- Is there a firewall that's giving you trouble?  Try to telnet to the port. Is the firewall stateful?
- Is the DNS too slow (use IP address instead of hostname, try DNS lookup)
- Do you close the connections? Are you overloading the Listener?

Comment: Thanks for the options Robert. Firewall is not preventing it since I am not getting this everytime, secondly DNS speed may be an issue. Am checking it out. thanks again

Comment: Best way to analyze is to start SQL trace.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem, I tried using the IP address instead of the host name in the database URL, and it worked for me.

Example jdbc:

```
...(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS.....(HOST=1.1.1.1)..)
```

Comment: The ip-address worked because the host name wasn't fully qualified or wasn't being resolved

Answer (score -1):

I would have a closer look and perhaps set a break point in

```
at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.handleIOException(TTC7Protocol.java:3678)
```

to see the precise IOException handled.  This will tell you the underlying cause, which can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thnks man, But am running this from Lotus Domino server and I can't put break point there unfortunately :(

Comment: This is hardly useful advice unless the OP has the source code of Oracle's JDBC driver, which isn't likely.

Comment: Even if you do not have the source code, you can still - at least in Eclipse - set a method breakpoint and investigate the call stack.  IDEA Intellij 14 has a built in decompiler.